# AWS : Rewrite non www to www with https

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront

I read pretty much all topics here but I really can't find out how to solve my problem. Here's my situation in AWS.

I had a website running in an EC2 instance with simple HTTP protocol.

**Previous situation**

In Route 53 :

- I had my www.example.com as A (type) pointing to my EC2 instance IP
- I had my example.com as A (type) pointing to an empty S3 bucket (named example.com) that made the redirect to www.example.com

Everything went well. Then I decided to move to HTTPS protocol.

**Current situation**

- Load balancer with all SSL stuff and certificate related to the EC2 instance.
- In Route 53, www.example.com as A (type) points to the load balancer.

I have www.example.com -> https://www.example.com

BUT

I just can't figure out how to do that :

- https://example.com -> https://www.example.com
- example.com -> https://www.example.com

As you understand I want a **https://www.example.com** base

I tried to configure cloudfront but I failed. And I don't know if I still need the S3 bucket. I read that cloudFront was supposed to do the link between Route 53 and the S3 bucket but I'm not sure.

Where I blocked is that :

- I let the redirect configuration of the S3 bucket
- I set up cloudfront with name of the s3 bucket (not the ID) as origin
- In Route 53 I set up for example.com as A (type) to the cloudfront

But nothing worked. I think I missed something related to cloudfront. I don't know if the config options changed but most of topics I read didn't explain all the options.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Question: Does example.com and www.example.com resolve correctly to your website? Does only 1 of them resolve?

Comment: I think the answer you seek lies here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/tutorial-redirecting-dns-queries.html . In essence, what you have to do is create CNAMEs of your CloudFront distributions.

Comment: Hey Austin. example.com leads to https://example.com and www.example.com leads to https://www.example.com. So the first one is not good for me.

Comment: Any success with the document? Once you have CloudFront and select the option for HTTP to HTTPS redirect you no longer have to worry about it. So what is left there is to add record that redirects **example.com** to **www.example.com**.

Comment: Hey AlexK, I did it but it still leads me to "https:// example.com" but now, the page is not safe anymore SSL problem I think

Comment: Please check the document and especially step 4. Then you need to create CNAME pointing to your CloudFront distribution.